Error creating DomainMapping: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'run.domainmappings.create' denied on resource
Trying to apply the following resource in Terraform. However I get the following error: Error creating DomainMapping: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'run.domainmappings.create' denied on resource x (or resource may not exist)
resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "this" {
  location = var.gcp_location
  name     = var.gcp_service_domain

  metadata {
    namespace = var.gcp_service_name
  }

  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_v2_service.this.name
  }
}

The service account I'm using has 57 assigned permissions. When I want to add run.domainmappings.create it doesn't show up as an option. Is it because domain mappings are in preview?


I haven't found the IAM role for that permission either (read the docs from Cloud Run, IAM for whole GCP, and for the Domain Mapping section) but it doesn't specified what IAM roles are needed to administer this. Probably due for this service being in preview.
Might be an overkill but would it be possible for you to assign the roles/dns.admin or if that doesn't work editor/owner?

roles/dns.admin didn't help. Adding editor/owner isn't option due to security reasons

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#limitations According to this page it's not product-ready. Sad

Can you do it through the Console? And if so, can you add the same permissions that your account has to the account you are using in Terraform?

I wasn't able to find it in the UI, but I was able to add it with gcloud.
If you're not already using a custom Role, create one and add it to your service account.
Then add the specific permission.
gcloud iam roles update MyRoleName --add-permissions="run.domainmappings.create"

You may also want to add run.domainmappings.get.

Weird inconsistency, thanks for sharing!
